# How do I install Python 2.7 on Windows without messing up my current Python 3 installation

Tags: windows-10, python

I need to install Python 2.7 for a project, but I already have Python 3 installed on my Windows 10 computer and I am afraid that if I install Python 2.7 it may override or uninstall Python 3. I can't find anything about this particular question online and so I wanted to check to make sure that nothing bad will happen to my current installation of Python 3 and if something bad will happen: how to avoid it. Basically, I want to know if installing Python 2 will break Python 3 and what the best way to install Python 2 alongside Python 3 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if installing Python 2 will break Python 3 and what the best way to install Python 2 alongside Python 3 is.

Python 2.7 and Python 3 can exist on the same system.  You will have to be specific, when you call Python from a script or a command prompt, in order to use a specific Python version.

> Running simply the command python the executable that is first met in PATH will be chosen for launch. In other words, add the Python directories manually. The one you add first will be selected when you type python.
>
> No matter the order of "pythons" you can:
>
> - run Python 2.x scripts using the command: py -2 (Python 3.x functionality) (ie. the first Python 2.x installation program found in
>   your PATH will be selected)
> - run Python 3.x scripts using the command: or py -3 (ie. the first Python 3.x installation program found in your PATH will be selected)

Source: [How to install both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7)